# Format user text based on the drop down selection

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to change the color, size and font type of the text that user has input. I am not able to pass these values to next page. I tried passing multiple parameters through POST, but it threw error

```
<html>
<body>

<form method = "POST" action="ass3_8_output.php">
<textarea id="input" name="input" placeholder="Enter text here" rows="6" cols="50" style="color:'option style'">
</textarea><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send"><br><br>
<label for "font color">Font color </lable>
<select id="font color" name="font color">
    <option disabled ="disabled" selected="selected">Select color</option>
    <option style ="color:red" value="Red">Red</option>
    <option style="color:green" value="Green">Green</option>
</select><br><br>

<label for"font type">Select font style </lable>
<select name="font type" id="font type">
    <option value="Lucida Console">Lucida Console</option>
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
</select><br><br>

<label for"font size">Select font size </lable>
<select name="font size" id="font size">
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
</select><br><br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php page

```
<?php
//pass name as parameter
$text=$_POST['input'];

echo"$text";
?>
```

Comment: You have to use sessions

Answer (score 0):

Attributes "id" and "name" must not have spaces, you can replace it with "-" or "_". Example:

Bad:

```
<select id="font color" name="font-color">
```

Good:

```
<select id="font-color" name="font-color">
```

In PHP, you can get the values with `$_POST['name_of_input']`.

If you want, use `var_dump($_POST); die();` to see all the data posted from the form and debug it.